# List of int get the records up to a certain value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List<int>` and I need all the first records that total reaches a value

`List<int> Values= new List{10,30,70,50,60};`
and value is 100 so i need list with 10,30,70 how can i get it with linq

Comment: Yes I can get it with for loop I want to do it in LINQ and in project its even a bit complicated than that

Comment: Does it have to be 100 or the nearest value below 100? And 10,30 and 70 results in 110, not 100.

Comment: better you add the for loop logic too

Comment: it has to be less value nearest to 100

Comment: `.TakeWhile(item => (sum += item) < 100)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko maybe `<=`?

Comment: As you were wondering about the downvote, I will give you my external understanding of it. But Im not the voter. Your question is unclear. At first the text of your question looked "find closest subset that sum to a target value.". A classical Homework question about subset. But your Expected result didn't match. With so little sentece and no clear explanation of your logic for those expected result, the reader is left with 2 choices. Either your question is exact and the result is not, or Your question is unclear so we don't understand the result.

Comment: You should read [ask] and [mcve]. They are good boilerplate for question. For "simple" question like that try to Always add at least the logic that leads to expected result in few lines. An answer even a good answer is not a sign of a quality question. If I will [edit] the question a bit. Don't get overwhelmed by a downvote. It's a feedback, don't be afraid of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on *Linq*, try `TakeWhile` (take `item` while `sum` is small):

```
List<int> Values = new List<int>() {
  10, 30, 70, 50, 60};

int sum = 0;

var result = Values
  .TakeWhile(item => (sum += item) <= 100) // or < depending on shall we stop on 100 or not
  .ToList();
```

However, good old `for` loop looks *more clean* (no ugly `sum` outside Linq query):

```
  List<int> result = new List<int>();

  // or sum < 100
  for (int i = 0, sum = 0; i < Values.Count && sum <= 100; sum += Values[i++])
    result.Add(Values[i]);
```

Comment: why the question is getting -1 ok thanks this what I'm looking for from morning

Comment: Urrgh. You've used external state in a LINQ query.

Comment: @avinash Maybe because you did not show any effort on your part. Your current code, why it fails. Where it fails, etc...